# Are SSIS Packages an option?

Tags: sql, .net, ssis

We are developing a .NET tool that will generate a Word document every year. 
We start with a bunch of data and end up with a docx file.

We came up with an algorithm to interpret the data, and generate the document. 
That's all contained within a DLL. The data is represented by classes Module, Table, Row. **We just need a way to convert the actual data to those classes. And then generate and save the document in a database.**

**How would I go about doing this?**

**Are SSIS Packages an option?** I know they can be scheduled to run every year. 
The SSIS Package should use our DLL. It should create our Module, Table and Row objects and populate it with data. Then use those objects to generate the document. Can it do that?

In other words, **can SSIS Packages map columns to objects' properties? And then call a method with those objects as arguments?**

I'm pretty sure that it's possible. But I'm afraid I'm trying to do something highly unorthodox, no?

Comment: What is the source of the data?  If your question is how to generate hydrated classes from data, one way to do that is to deserialize XML files.  Otherwise, I think you need a software layer that reads the data, news up the appropriate classes, and stuffs the data into those classes.

Comment: The source is said to be XML. I have not yet received a set of data.
But I the original source is a database. I was thinking I could skip the conversion to XML that the client is planning to do.
The other software layer you speak of would be the obvious way to go.

Comment: Doesn't a standard word merge contain enough functionality for you? compiled DLL's and SSIS seems way over the top.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, however, it will required a little coding. My suggestions would be first generate an standard ssis template of what you would like it to behave. Then look into http://etldevelopernotes.blogspot.com/2012/05/metadata-driving-package-generator.html. In here there are ideas and some code on how to generate ssis packages using .net code. In other words you would be able to call your DLL and assign all your values to a virtual package that would be generated at run time. For how to do a mapping check :
http://etldevelopernotes.blogspot.com/2012/05/sqlsaturday-130-demo-7.html 
hope this helps.
J. Novo

Comment: Alright. Time to learn more about SSIS Packages and generating them.

Comment: I also highly recommend looking at EzAPI as an easier and more .Net-friendly way of generating SSIS packages.